# tryparse method for positive integer is not returning an error with inputs that are not integers

Tags: c#, while-loop, integer, tryparse

I have the following code:

```
int orderQuantity;

Write("Number of Items: \t");
while(int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity) && orderQuantity > 0 == false)
{
     Write("Error: Number of Items must be a positive, whole number: \t");
     int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity);
}
```

The goal is that while the input is not a positive integer, continue to return an error. Once the input is a positive integer, continue on.

The problem is this logic only works with the negative numbers. When I try to make the code into `while(!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity) && orderQuantity > 0 == false)`

I run into the code not recognizing integers nor negative numbers as errors.

Comment: Use `while (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity) || orderQuantity <= 0)`  - "While the line couldn't be parsed as an int OR the parsed value was less than or equal to zero". And remove the parse inside the loop - it's being done in the `while` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
while(!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity) || orderQuantity <= 0)
{
    Write("Error: Number of Items must be a positive, whole number: \t");
}
```

So you have to handle the cases that it's not a valid integer and that it's valid but not greater than zero separately. Also remove the `TryParse` from the loop body.

Comment: I'm getting the following errors: CS0019 Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int' and CS0029 Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'. Both errors seem odd to me though. I must have messed up the syntax, so copying your solution exactly seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to parenthesize the condition so this :

```
int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity) && orderQuantity > 0 == false
```

changed to be this :

```
(int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity) && orderQuantity > 0) == false
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension method might help you to get code that is more expressive and thus more easy to read:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static bool IsPositiveInt32(this string input, out int value)
   {
      if(!int.TryParse(input, out value))
      {
         return false;
      }
      return value > 0;
   }
}
```

Usage will be

```
int orderQuantity;
Write("Number of Items: \t");
while(!ReadLine().IsPositiveInt32(out orderQuantity))
{
    Write("Error: Number of Items must be a positive, whole number: \t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while((!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out orderQuantity)) || (orderQuantity <= 0))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.